# Consecutio implicita

Tags: grammar

**Premessa**: non intendo entrare nel merito *del contenuto* del tweet di Claudio Messora:

> Cara Laura, volevo tranquillizzarti.. anche se noi
>   del blog di Grillo fossimo tutti potenziali stupratori,
>   ...tu non corri nessun rischio!

Non entro nemmeno nel merito della punteggiatura piuttosto ardita: vorrei invece soffermarmi sulla consecutio temporum.

In italiano standard ci sarebbe voluto un condizionale: "tu non **correresti** nessun rischio", e su questo direi non ci sono dubbi. Ma in un italiano colloquiale potrebbe avere senso un indicativo, immaginando una frase come "non corri alcun rischio, [e non lo correresti ne]anche se..."?

Comment: Temo che nel linguaggio comune sia un modo diffuso e questo si rispecchia nei messaggi in cui non si cerca nemmeno di subordinare. Lo spreco di puntini serve a nascondere le carenze nella sintassi.

Comment: mau, non credo sia la versione originale, almeno quella che io lessi; lì mancava una 'z' in 'tranquillizzarti', che nella tua versione c'è.

Comment: sì, me ne sono accorto dopo aver scritto la domanda che avevo automaticamente corretto l'ortografia. Ma visto che non era l'ortografia che mi interessava, ho deciso di lasciare così

Answer (score 4):

Alzi le vele omai la navicella del nostro ingegno (cit.) e concentriamoci per un momento su un illustre periodo ipotetico:

> «State contenti, umana gente, al quia;
>
> ché, se possuto aveste veder tutto,
>
> mestier non era parturir Maria.»
>
> (Dante Alighieri, La Divina Commedia - Purgatorio III, 37-39)

E la perifrasi è:

> Umani, aggrappatevi con forza ai fatti per quel che sono;
>
> perché, se aveste potuto veder tutto [e questa è la [protasi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/protasi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)]
>
> non ***era*** necessario che Maria partorisse [e questa è l'[apodosi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/apodosi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)].

È la «protasi di un'ipotetica irreale […] ma apodosi agganciata a fatto realmente avvenuto [sic!]» (Dante Alighieri, La Divina Commedia - Purgatorio, a cura di Daniele Mattalia, BUR 2009).

Cioè mentre la subordinata ipotetica è chiaramente irreale (--> non possiam veder tutto), la reggente è reale perché Maria ha davvero partorito; quindi, l'apodosi richiede l'indicativo - o vogliamo forse metter in dubbio il fatto (quia!) che, invece, conosciamo con certezza per verità rivelata? Non sia mai!, sottointende il Poeta …

Secondo la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/periodo-ipotetico_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/), questa forma è attestata «nell'italiano letterario dei primi secoli»; ed è «perno del sistema substandard dell’italiano d’oggi» …

Answer (score 0):

Non sono d'accordo con Gianni: per me è un anacoluto. I puntini fanno da separatore e allo stesso tempo cerniera tra due "mondi" diversi.

Comment: Allora non sei d'accordo neanche con randomatlabuser, che ha scritto (con parole molto migliori) quello che dicevo io.

Comment: Può darsi, all'epoca il suo intervento non c'era. (PS. Non è mio il -1)

Answer (score -1):

A mio avviso l'indicativo è corretto. L'idea è: "ti tranquillizzo, tu non corri alcun rischio. E non lo correresti neanche se fossimo stupratori. "

Quindi la frase principale è proprio "tu non corri alcun rischio", ed effettivamente il messaggio principale del tweet è ivi contenuto.

Con il congiuntivo cambia la frase principale.